# Changing a Private variable OR defining a Range variable. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

OK, so I'm working with VBA in excel, and I've come across an issue. Basically, someone has already programmed this workbook to do what I need to do, however, I've made some changes and can't figure out how to change the one line of code to work.

There is a 'Create New Month' macro that eventually calls upon a "SetupEachDay" sub. It copies sheets A, B, C, and D in a particular order to create the new file. I've modified the 4 sheets to contain the data I want as an appropriate template. When copying the sheets, the code copies `Range("B13")` which apparently only copies columns A-L from A/B/C/D to the new sheets. I need the function to copy from `A2:Q82`.

I can't find where `B13` is defined, and I don't know how to change it to copy the entire sheet. I tried just putting `Range("A2:Q82")` but it didn't work.

Help?

Code:

```
Counter = 1 'initialize counter
While (Counter < 32)
    If ((DatePart("w", Worksheets(Counter).Range("A1"))) <> "7" And (DatePart("w", Worksheets(Counter).Range("A1"))) <> "1") Then
        Worksheets("E").Range(Worksheets("Setup").Range("B13")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(Counter).Range("A2")
    End If
Counter = Counter + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Either try the psychic hotline or show us the code in question :).

Comment: Just pasted it up above in the original question. Thanks

Comment: `Worksheets("E").Range(Worksheets("Setup").Range("B13")).Copy` is the source range!

Comment: I know this. I need to CHANGE B13 to grab A2:Q82. Right now it's defined SOMEWHERE as A2:L47.

Comment: What's in `Worksheets("Setup).range("B13")`? I'm sure it will be `$A$2:$L$47`

Comment: It looks like the range to be copied is stored in cell B13 in the "Setup" worksheet. For example cell B13 might contain something like "A:L", which is then used to define the range in the "E" worksheet that is copied to the sheet specified in the loop. That's my best guess. Please tell us what's in cell B13 of the sheet named "Setup".

Comment: Yes, i kinda agree with Doug. The value of `B13` on `Setup` worksheet holds the address.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("E").Range("A2:Q82").Copy
```

Should do the trick if you're happy to hard code the range.